# Logistic regression: Is it valid to code NA as 0?

Tags: logistic, missing-data

Hi I have the following problem:

I plan to do a logistic regression on web traffic data. One of my attributes is Number of days since last visit (type numeric in R). Now lots of visitors are firs-timers and I have no data for this attribute. Should I code them as NAs, or is is valid to code them as 0s?

Thank you all

Comment: It is funny that what I'd call trial-and-error has actually a scientific name :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it trial-and-error. The idea is not to find values that happen to work but rather how dependent you are on your assumptions - and the proper interpretation is that if there's a large difference your results will be unreliable for both values you tested.

Comment: @Procrastinator: I'm not sure, but doesn't the work of Dan Jackson pertain to missings in the dependent variable? It seems to me that Peter has missings in an independent variable of the logistic regression.

Comment: @ I am affraid you are correct. Fixed.

Comment: @Erik I have understood. Nevertheless, from an ML perspective, if I perform a Crossvalidation where I apply the input method only during training and compare it to the true outcome during testing (i.e. to all instances where I know the label), I can safely pick the input method which has reduced the bias more (with respect to the variance, statistical significance etc.). So, in summary, this is trial and error to optimize bias reduction, although [sensitivity analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis) IN GENERAL aims for something else ;).

Comment: Sure, this is valid method. Though I would argue that trial-and-error is already a valid scientific term :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say "no". If you have this as a numeric variable, then 0 would be less than 1, indicating an even more frequent visitor; indeed, 0 has a sensible interpretation as "visited the site today".

Comment: Thanks Peter, so how would you impute them? The percentage of 1st time visitors is obviously very high (70 %).

Comment: I agree with @Peter Flom. If you are asking "what is the association of days since last visit with outcome", your study population is "visitors who have visited the site more than once". First time visitors are not included in this population. You could perform a regression on all visitors without including "days since last visit", and then perform a second regression on the sub-population that are repeat-visitors to explore associations with "days since last visit" in that sub-population.

Comment: @jthetzel Thanks JT. That seems like a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the direct question, no.  As @PeterFlom points out, 0 has the interpretation "visited today."  You likely already have a lot of 0's in your data from people who did just that.

I don't know that I would call this data "missing".  The data is all there, it's just that the interpretation is a little difficult.  To make this clear, think about what would happen if you imputed the missing data--what would you impute it to?  You're stuck with the same problem.  You know what the data is, but you do not know how to model it.

Similarly, if you code it as NA, what does that mean for the model?  You still have to make a choice as to how to model it.  Row-wise deletion would work, but alter the question you are answering to, "Among previous visitors...."

Some potential ways of modeling this:

- Make it a really high number (close to $\infty$)
- Create a two-part model, the first stage of which models the decision to become a "customer" of the website, the second stage is what you have now
- Create a dummy for first-time visitor (`first`), and interact it with the number of days since last visit variable (`visit`).  E.g. include `first` and `first*visit` without including `visit`.

Of those, the 2-part model seems the most appropriate but it's a lot more work.  The others would probably get you something reasonable in a pinch.  You could even compare across the three approaches and get a crude sensitivity analysis that way.

Comment: I agree that the two-part model is the appropriate one.

Answer (score 2):

If the outcome of interest is number of days since last visit, then first-time users don't provide any information about that outcome, so it seems like leaving out first time visitors is the only thing to do.

In any case, coding first time users as `0` reflects a belief that first time users are equivalent to a person who has visited the website before, and whose last visit was 0 days ago, which doesn't make much sense. Therefore, I'd strongly advise against coding in this way, since it would seriously damage interpretability of your results.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is neither.  You should code them as missing,  a simple dot for missing numerical data if you use SAS.  The use of 0 is bad because the software will treat 0 as a number when the data point is actually missing.  The use of NA is no good because you have a numerical variable and you are mixing character and numerical values for the same variable.  It might work in SAS though because I think SAS will convert values that it doesn't recognize into missing.  But play it safe identify those cases as missing numerical data.  The modeling procedure should know how to deal with that.

Comment: FYI, in R (which I think the original poster is using) NA and missing are the same thing

Comment: No, I don't think they are missing. The data are there. These are not people for whom you don't know the last date they visited the site, they are people (per the post) who *never* did so.

Comment: @PeterFlom, in R (and I'd imagine in SAS), calling these values "missing" will just omit them from the model fitting, which I think we all agree is what should be done (rather than giving them some numeric value).

Comment: @Macro Yes, that's what would happen in SAS (as in R). I think the best solution is a 2 part model, which treats them as missing in only one part. The data aren't really "missing" in the traditional sense. That would be "I don't know what this value is". Here, it's "I know what the value is, but it's hard to deal with appopriately"